# Ejabbered sending duplicate push

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I have did

```
mConnection.setUseStreamManagement(false);
mConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(false);
```

When ever i'm sending Presence **unavailable** to ejabberD server sending push from FCM and also receiving my side but whenever i set Presence again to **available** that time eJabbered send me all the push which are send through FCM which are duplicate.

So, what i have to do for manage this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: is it happening with muc or one to one ??

Comment: one to one and both

Comment: are u sending the presence status to server every time u enter n leave the app ??

Comment: yes i'm sending status for available and unavailable when i need to offline user and reonline

Comment: I faced this issue with MUC every time i rejoin group i was getting all message since the group was created so i fixed it by EnterConfigurationBuilder for which im passing my last seen n oly those group messages are received since i left the group.. but i dono why u are facing it with one to one chat

Comment: but what you did for MUC ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145092/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-moulesh).